# Is eating food from person who receives or pays interest haram?

Tags: halal-haram, food, riba

I heard that eating food is haram in homes where the main income is from interest (riba) or the persons in the home pays it willingly. 
What I heard is right or wrong?
Is there any specific authentic hadith regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if the person whose income source is riba, invites you to eat food, then, it is ok.
Even taking gift from Kafirs are acceptable.

Comment: Post references for your claim.